# Suppose i created three or four object of a class study then memory will be created seperatly or not?

Tags: c++

Here

```
class study
{  
   some data member;  
   some member function;
};

main()
{
    study s1, s2, s3;
}
```

It will create three object of class study then memory created seperatly for seperate object or not in c++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure what you're asking here but...

Obviously s1,s2 and s3 will each occupy different areas of memory.

However, the memory allocated for them is on the stack, so there will be no calls to `malloc()/new()` to actually 'allocate' memory.

Allocating memory off the stack is fast (just a subtraction from the stack pointer) so to allocate 3 'studys' there is typically just a single assembler instruction to do something like `SUB 3*sizeof(study)` from SP.

Comment: @user588877, just as a complementary info: Like Roddy said, in your example you allocate your object on the stack (it's a little memory, something like 1MByte I think, that the CPU uses for all its calculation). In other cases you can allocate bigger chunks of memory doing `int main(){ study * pstudy1 = new study(); }`. But its slower. That latter allocation style (using the new operator) is called dynamic allocation, allocated on the heap that is roughly all your available RAM memory (not on the CPU's stack).

Answer (score 0):

A class is just a user defined datatype. So just like how for a datatype memory is different for different variables similarly for classes and objects also. Of course separate for different object.

Answer (score 0):

need more clarity on your question. Are you asking if they would share a single memory (which is not possible), since they are declared in a single line? Or are you asking whether the memory is allocated yet, since they are not defined yet?